# Javascript: replaceAll inside the eval is not working

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I have a javascript code inside java nashorn engine `eval`. 
Something like this

```
engine.eval("<code>.... print(printIt.substring(1) + '==>Value:' + obj[property].replaceAll('\n', ' ').....<code>");
```

Here I want to replace all occurence of `\n` and `\r` with simple space.
But when I run this I get error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: :1:426
>   Missing close quote

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your code is missing a close quote.

Comment: @Pointy: My code doesn't miss any closing quote. If I remove `.replaceAll()`, it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making mistake of not escaping the backward slash of `\n`.

If you are doing `.replaceAll('\n', '<somethng>')`, you are literally searching for newline and replacing, which is not equal to searching for `\n` string.

Here is how you should do with escaping:

```
obj[property].replaceAll('\\n', ' ').replaceAll('\\r', ' ') \\for replacing all newline and carriage return.
```

**On the sidenote:** BTW, I am interested in knowing why are you replacing `\r` it's not much of use doing this as it's not used alone these days very often. Here is the definitions of `\r` and `\n`.

**`\r`** = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS before X

`\n` = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character in Unix/Mac OS X

`\r\n` = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows